# jQuery UI draggable and adding class on drag event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to add a class to the draggable event using jQuery UI.

However the following code that I've written is not working as expected;

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.sortable div.draggable').draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) { ui.helper.addClass('move'); },
    });
});
```

Essentially I am trying to add a drop shadow (using the move class) to the div.draggable. What am I doing wrong as the drag event works, but the drop shadow does not appear?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 17):

From the [jQuery UI Draggable documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/):

> . During drag the element also gets a class of ui-draggable-dragging

You could just write the CSS to leverage this class as opposed to trying to add a class.

Comment: @Blackersoul - The CSS from the CDN is just the base CSS. You can still write your own CSS (or JavaScript) to leverage or change the default behavior of those classes.

Answer (score 6):

Same CSS inheritance still applies. If you have your own stylesheet include something like

```
.ui-draggable-dragging{
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
}
```

If you do not have a stylesheet. You can still add this inline within your html files using `<style>` tags

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that we add a new `class` **my_class** on dargging start, then the code should be like:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.sortable div.draggable').draggable({
         start: function( event, ui ) {
              $(this).addClass('my_class'); 
         }
    });
});
```

css:

```
.my_class{
/* YOUR CLASS CSS */
}
```

Refer this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Bz4GN/) for adding and removing class on drag start and drag end

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option classes: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-classes

for example:

```js
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
    classes: {
      "ui-draggable": "move"
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```