# Change HTML when on start dragging with Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I've been working on a drag and drop UI with jquery UI.

I have a bunch of elements like this, that are draggable:

```
 <a href="#" draggable="true" id="server" class="draggable"><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-fw"></i> Server</a>
```

I can drag and clone this onto a drop zone.  But when I start dragging the original element, I want to change the HTML to be

```
<i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5"></i>
```

The current code looks like this, but should I be doing something in the start event handler to clone, and change the html of the cloned element?

```
function MakeDraggable(ele) {
    ele.draggable({
        grid: [20, 20 ],
        //revert: "invalid",
        helper: 'move'
    });
}

$(function() {

    // Make the .draggable class  a Draggable
    //
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        grid: [ 20, 20 ],
        helper: 'clone',
        appendTo: '#dropzone-panel',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("Dragging me.....");
        }
    });

    // Setup the dropzone
    //
    $("#dropzone-panel").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("Drop Event Fired");

            // Get the original element id
            var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");

            // If this element is a copy already
            // then dont clone it.
            //
            if (id.indexOf("-copy-") >= 0) {
                console.log("This is a copy");
            } else {
               // This is the orginal, so clone and create a new id 
               var number_of_clones = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="'+id+"-copy-" +'"]').length;
                console.log("found [" +number_of_clones +"] copies");
                var pos = ui.position;
                var $obj = ui.draggable.clone().attr("id", id+"-copy-"+number_of_clones);
                $obj.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: pos.top + "px",
                    left: pos.left + "px"
                });
                $obj.appendTo("#dropzone-panel");

                // Make the clone draggable
                MakeDraggable($obj);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI draggable and adding class on drag event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724908/jquery-ui-draggable-and-adding-class-on-drag-event)

Comment: The solution wasnt an exact fit, but gave me enough to figure it out.  After I clone the element, I then extract the child and change it's class.  This changes the look of the element after I drop it.